# Unable to modify Kotlin MutableMap

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

I have created a map with the following:

```kotlin
var names = mutableMapOf<String, Map<String, List<String>>>(
    "test" to mapOf(
        "first" to listOf(
            "Spongebob", "Patrick"
        ),
        "last" to listOf(
            "Squarepants", "Star"
        )
    )
)
```

Next I would like to modify the map, which I think intuitively would be something like:

```kotlin
names["test"]["first"].add("Squidward")
```

However, this line is giving me an error: `Expecting a top level declaration`

I don't understand this; is my MutableMap definition not the declaration?

I'm coming from Python, so I'm expecting to be able to access my dict by keys and edit as necessary.

Comment: Can you show us your whole file? I suspect your issue is not putting code in a function. Unlike python, kotlin requires code to be in a function, and doesn't execute the file top to bottom.

Comment: Additionally as @Orest Shemeliuk points out you are trying to modify an immutable map and an immutable list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PiRocks pointed out in a comment, the issue was that I wasn't wrapping it all in a function.

I ultimately solved the issue by separating out the nested dict structure and creating sub classes with their own "first" and "last" list variables. I think this reduced complexity in my case and it now seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a list which is immutable, try this:

```
 var names = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>>(
        "test" to mutableMapOf(
            "first" to mutableListOf(
                "Spongebob", "Patrick"
            ),
            "last" to mutableListOf(
                "Squarepants", "Star"
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Why was the answer downvoted , seems there's nothing wrong in the answer, `"first"` must be a `MutableList<String>` in order to add elements to it.